# On Samsung Omnia, a Java MIDLet cannot connect after the GPRS connection is shut down by the phone

Tags: java-me

i have an Java J2ME application that does (at user request) create HttpConnections to a server. The application works properly on most phones, including Samsung Omnia.

The problem on this (Omnia) is that at some point, the phone disconnects from the GPRS network. The application is still in use but not trying to make connections to the server (the user is browsing data).

After this happens, when the user requests some update from the server, the phone refuses to re-connect to GPRS.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that it was a resource management problem. In particular, remember to close every object (input and output streams, connections, etc).

Comment: Also open http connections on a separate thread to avoid deadlock. Also make sure that you don't open more that 4 connections at a time. Because most phones have a limit of 4 connections